# Installing gdal python library on windows using conda (DLL load failed)

Tags: python, conda, gdal

I am trying to install gdal in windows using conde:

```
> conda install gdal
```

When I try:

```
import gdal
```

I get this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-ee38efafc30b> in <module>()
----> 1 import gdal

C:\Users\milad\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\gdal.py in <module>()
      1 # import osgeo.gdal as a convenience
----> 2 from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
      3 deprecation_warn('gdal')
      4 
      5 from osgeo.gdal import *

C:\Users\milad\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py in <module>()
     23                 fp.close()
     24             return _mod
---> 25     _gdal = swig_import_helper()
     26     del swig_import_helper
     27 else:

C:\Users\milad\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py in swig_import_helper()
     19         if fp is not None:
     20             try:
---> 21                 _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
     22             finally:
     23                 fp.close()

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

It does not say what dll it is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `import gdal` use `from osgeo import gdal`.

```py
from osgeo import gdal
print(gdal.VersionInfo("–version"))

#> GDAL 3.6.3, released 2023/03/07
```

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled to get GDAL working for python so I posted a guide here: https://github.com/felipunky/GISPython/blob/master/README.md scroll down to the "Installing the libraries that we will use in our python script" section.