# How can i install gdal for python in windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, gdal

I'm trying to install gdal library. i've tried the things recomended here [Installing gdal python library on windows using conda (DLL load failed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341797/installing-gdal-python-library-on-windows-using-conda-dll-load-failed)

and here: https://github.com/felipunky/GISPython/blob/master/README.md

then i tried:

```
C:\Users\User>pip install D:\Seba\Programas\GDAL-3.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: GDAL==3.3.0 from file:///D:/Seba/Programas/GDAL-3.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (3.3.0)
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 21.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\User>python
Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'
>>> from osgeo import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 670, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 583, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1043, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 31, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_gdal')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'
>>>
```

any recomendation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

conda install of gdal in windows does work.

You haven't given much to go on, but my guess is that you have not activated the conda environment into which gdal has been installed.

Normally your command prompt would look like this, if you had activated it

```
(gdal_env_name) C:\Users\User>python
```

Also, run

```
conda list
```

to check that all the expected libraries are there.

Answer (score 0):

You can install GDAL on windows using Anaconda package management system

**Install Anaconda**

Full *Anaconda*  has more than 500 Mb of pre-downloaded libraries libraries. Most probably you will use only few of them. Additionally some of libraries you would like to use are not a part of default anaconda channel at all (for example GDAL library).

That's why the preferred installer of *conda* manager is *Miniconda*. It includes just the necessary libraries to just work (*conda* along with some required libraries).

https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

**Run the installer**

Run Miniconda installer. Default settings are fair enough.

**Make conda-forge the default channel (optional)**

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

**Install python packages**

Start [Anaconda prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gZqV.png) and execute following commands:

**Create dedicated virtual Python environment (optional)**

```
conda create -n dev
conda activate dev
conda install -c conda-forge  python=3.10
```

**Instal GDAL library**

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

**Install other Python libraries**

```
conda install -c conda-forge xlsxwriter openpyxl pandas geopandas matplotlib psycopg requests keyring
```

**Check GDAL environment**

Enter in the Command Prompt:

```
python --version
gdalinfo --version
```

**Execute some GDAL code**

```py
from osgeo import gdal
print(gdal.VersionInfo("–version"))

#> GDAL 3.6.3, released 2023/03/07
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this once: sudo easy_install GDAL

Comment: Thank you, but i was trying to do it in windows