# ERROR: Failed building wheel for osgeo, Failed to build osgeo

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, gdal, osgeo

when i install osgeo on my anaconda prompt i got the error message looks like "      Exception: In order to be able to run `from osgeo import gdal`,
You were probably trying to install `gdal` by running `pip install osgeo`.
Instead, you should either `pip install gdal` or replace `osgeo` with `gdal` in your requirements.
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for osgeo
Failed to build osgeo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for osgeo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects"

My installcommand:
pip install osgeo

I want to install the osgeo on my anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Make sure you have the necessary development libraries and headers for gdal installed on your system. Since you're using Windows, you can download the GDAL library for Windows from the following link: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)
   Choose the appropriate wheel file based on your Python version and system architecture (e.g., cp38 for Python 3.8 and win_amd64 for 64-bit). Download the .whl file to a directory on your computer.

*Open the Anaconda Prompt and navigate to the directory where you downloaded the gdal wheel file.
Install the gdal package using pip and the downloaded wheel file. Replace your_wheel_file.whl with the actual filename:*

> > pip install your_wheel_file.whl

*After the installation is complete, try importing gdal in the Anaconda Prompt or a Python script:*

> > from osgeo import gdal

*If everything goes well, you should be able to import gdal without any errors.
Keep in mind that the version numbers and filenames mentioned in the commands above may differ based on the version of gdal and your Python interpreter. Make sure to use the correct filename for the wheel you downloaded.*

Answer (score 1):

Use following snippet to install GDAL on Anaconda environment:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

More detailed instructions you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76053127/2524798).